# Exchange and routing of messages

Tags: exchange-2007, multi-homed

I have Exchange 2007 installed on a W2k8 box with two NICs. How can I tell Exchange to route all outgoing SMTP traffic out via a specific NIC?

Edit: Can I do it via the W2k8 firewall/routing?

Comment: Maybe using differents metrics in your nic configurations

Comment: Problem being that I want almost all other traffic to go via main NIC. The NIC I want to use for SMTP will actually have higher metric...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be performed on the Edge Transport server according to Microsoft, so I am not sure if it will work on a Hub that is also handling Edge traffic.

Use the following PowerShell command to set the source IP:

```
Set-SendConnector "Connector Name" -SourceIPAddress a.b.c.d
```

More information is available on the [Set-SendConnector command here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998294.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Check this blog out: http://exchangepedia.com/blog/2008/03/routing-outbound-mail-using-particular.html. It explains how you have to do this through the Exchange Management Shell.

Please note the following:

> However, as noted in the documentation, this only works on Edge Transport servers. Hub Transport servers ignore the SourceIPAddress parameter.

Hope this helps.